# Reason for having to compile files to different extension types

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw, gnu

Recently I had to use this command in a makefile I had for an sqlite program I'm working on:

```
gcc -g -c sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o
g++ -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ sqlite3.o main.o -o sqliteex
```

I had to directly compile the sqlite3.c file into my program in order to use the sqlite3.h interface (included in the main.cpp file with #include SQL/sqlite3.h).  But why did I need to use gcc to do this and create sqlite3.o, then compile both files as .o files into my executable?

Edit: My guess would be that .o files are compilable by both gcc and g++, if this is the case, is it a good practice to just always compile things as .o files?

Comment: Probably because it's got both C and C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why did I need to use gcc to do this and create sqlite3.o, then compile both files as .o files into my executable?

You did not *need* to do that. The reason you *did* do that was to specify that sqlite.c was **C** code and not **C++** code. You could have done this instead:

```
g++ main.cpp -x c sqlite3.c -o sqliteex
```

Additionally, it is possible (but not at all certain) that the sqlite code could have compiled as C++, like this:

```
g++ main.cpp sqlite3.c -o sqliteex
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Wikipedia:

Single Compilation Unit is a technique of computer programming for the C/C++ languages, which reduces compilation time and aids the compiler to perform program optimization even when the compiler itself is lacking support for whole program optimization or precompiled headers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit

Development is mostly edit->compile until success cycle.  When you have separately compiled files you can just recompile only file which was modified, which makes rebuild much faster. Last line is not compilation but linking of compiled object files into target executable.

Also as Mysticial noted, you have mixture of C and C++